# BIRT:How to access the outer table values in inner table of Onprepare() event.?

Tags: birt

I have two tables.
I am not able to access the outer table value **row["Value"]** inside **Onprepare()** event of inner table in BIRT Report.
so I can use those value to set width of inner table column dynamically.
how to access outer table value in Onprepare() event?

There is no method for column. If I put the cell width gives error 12 cm
**stacktrace :**
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: There are errors evaluating script "this.width="12cm";":
Wrapped java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not set cell width, please set column width instead. (/report/body/table[@id="3482"]/detail/row[@id="3485"]/cell[@id="3486"]/table[@id="98041"]/detail/row[@id="98063"]/cell[@id="98066"]/method[@name="onCreate"]#1)

Comment: instead of onCreate() on `cell[@id="98066"]/`you should use onCreate() on `table[@id="98041"]`

Comment: how to set table column width from  table[@id="98041"]  ? please give example..

Comment: set column width is just a suggestion in this error message because you can't set cell width. While setting column width is fine you could also set table width instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the row of the outer table you could write some row values to a variable.
In the inner table you can access that variable.

edit:
you need a "variable" with a global access scope. One way to do so is initialize the variable in the report's initialize() script (beforeFactory() or onPrepare() are also valid options)

```
myVar1 = 0;     //has global scope
var myVar2 = 0; //has only local scope
```

**→ Try to move your innerTable's script from the onPrpare() to the onCreate()**

[here's a simple example report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/riy21hhdbtsae17/StackOverflow_q53481666.rptdesign?dl=0) (updated linked example with dynamic width)

In that example I pass a value of `1 | 2 | 3` from the outher to the inner table.
In the onCreate() of the inner table you could concat that value with an appropriate unit eg. `cm` or `in`.
Also check that you have 'Fixed Layout' (not 'Auto Layout') for the Report.

```
//"this" is the table
this.width = myVar1 + ' cm'; // set inner table width
```

edit: setting the inner table column's width instead of table width itself can also be done from the the onCreate() of that inner table.

```
/* initialize() of Report */
dynColWidth = null; // initialize a var with global scope to store an array

/* onCreate() of outerTable's Cell (using a DynamicText Field makes it more obvious) */
dynColWidth = [1*row["ID"], 2*row["ID"]];  // create the array with your 12 values here

/* onCreate() of innerTable ("this" is the table) */
var i;
for(i=0; i<this.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  this.getColumn(i).width = dynColumnWidth[i] + 'cm';
}
```

Comment: Variable value shows null inside OnPrepare() event.if I print in OnCreate() event its showing variable value.

Comment: you may need to check if your variable has a local or global scope. see my edit above

Comment: thanks for response. you are right we can access the variables in oncreate() but I want those value in Onprepare() so I can resize inner table column width.do you have any idea about how to resize table column width based on outer table values?This is urgent for me.

Comment: resize can be don during onCreate() event

Comment: gives error :java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not set cell width, please set column width instead.

Comment: onCreate() of the inner Table should be fine. Use the Outline View. You may have written to the onCreate() of the Cell from the outer or inner Table. But it should be on the Table itself.

Comment: Table column not showing in outline view.if I add width oncreate() it applied to whole table.

Comment: setting table width is exactly what I did in the liked example above

Comment: I want to set the Table column width .if I put this.width = "10cm" in table Oncreate()  but its changes the table width.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. How many columns does your inner table have? How many of them have dynamic width? If only one column is dynamic you can easily do that with the way I did show you how to set the table width dynamically

Comment: I have 12 columns in inner table all are dynamic and width of columns are bases on outer table values.please attach the source file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.